# Playstation store Destiny help

Tags: destiny

I have destiny on ps4 as a disk but I have none of the dlc's. I just bought the legendary edition and PlayStation store is saying cannot add the follwing content to downloads. A disc version of the same aplication has been used on this ps4, you must delete the disc Version. If I delete it and download the legendary edition will I still have my data.

Comment: you already asked this question

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, this question is more asking if he will have to delete his current data, then redownload it, while the other one is asking if he could still play his characters.

Answer (score 0):

You will still have your characters (they are saved on the server). However you will have to download the whole game, along with the expansions (roughly 37.4 gb according to my PS4).